# Multiple operators in an if statement without AND or OR

Tags: objective-c, syntax, if-statement, operators

I wanted to see if, instead of writing `if (row > -1 && row < _rows)` I could shorten it to `if (-1 < row < _rows)`.  I used the below test to find out (it didn't return any compile errors).

```
int x = 5;
BOOL test1 = NO;
BOOL test2 = NO;
BOOL test3 = NO;

if (x < 6 && x > 4) {
    test1 = YES;
}
if (4 < x < 6) {
    test2 = YES;
}
if (5 < x < 7) {
    test3 = YES;
}
```

All three tests came up `YES`, including the 3rd one which, if my syntax was correct, should've been `NO`.  It looks like this isn't valid syntax, but my question is, what is the compiler actually doing where the syntax `(5 < 5 < 7)` returns true?

Comment: This gets asked regularly, but it's hard to find the dupe in the duplicate.

Comment: To be clear, the syntax of the 2nd and 3rd `if` statements is not really valid. You must properly use `&&` like in the first `if` statement to get the expected result for the right reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because `5 < x` returns false, which casts to 0, which is less than 7.

Comment: And the second one is true for a similar reason, not just because x is between 4 and 6. First `4 < x` is true which is treated as 1. Then `1 < 6` is true so the `if` is treated as true.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to not use the logical and operator at all, this should work:

```
5 < x == 1 == (x < 7)
```

This evaluates to 1 == 1 == 1 , which is 1 == 1, which is a true value. The parentheses are needed because of how the compiler reads left to right.

Comment: Yep, or `5 < x == x < 7 == true` should do too, technically. Just got to think about how things evaluate (if you've done C++ and looked at overloading operators it'll make good sense)

Comment: Please do not ever write such code. I'm going to have nightmares from such code. Please write readable code.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, I was not condoning writing code like that. It is very unreadable and hard to maintain. I only answered it that way, because I was only wondering if such a thing would be possible, so I had a looked into it. Solving problems in other ways can be fun.